# Looping a reset function in Google Apps Script

Tags: function, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets, reset

I'm trying to loop the reset function so I can apply it across 30+ different sheets in the same spreadsheet.

I've found an answer in the past but I can't manage to modify it to work.

```
function reset() {
  var keys = ['my spreadsheet id']; // list of spreadsheet ids
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(keys[i]);
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('sheet name'); // i tried writing multiple sheet names here already but it doesn't work, hence trying to make the loop
    sheet.getRange('C3').setValue('X');
  }
}
```

The loop that I am talking about has been mentioned here: [One function for multiple sheets in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48206657/one-function-for-multiple-sheets-in-google-sheets)

I don't need to get all the sheets. 2 of the sheets should be excluded.
And I need help applying it to the function I have which is posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of sheets to be excluded and make sure they are not [included](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) when setting the value:

```
function reset() {
  const key = 'my spreadsheet id';
  const sheetsToExclude = ["Sheet2","testSheet"]; // add the sheet names you want to exclude
  const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(key).getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(sheet => {
       if(!sheetsToExclude.includes(sheet.getName())){    
           sheet.getRange('C3').setValue('X')
  }});
}
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for, perfect. Much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution:

You can use `getSheets()` to get all sheets in a spreadsheet, and `filter()` to exclude defined sheets:

```
function reset() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var exclude = ['Sheet1','Sheet2'];
  sheets.filter(s => exclude.indexOf(s.getName()) == -1).forEach(s => s.getRange('C3').setValue('Z'));
}
```

### Reference:

[getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets)

Comment: Hey. I don't need to get all the sheets. 2 of the sheets should be excluded.That's why I want to point toward each and every one.

Comment: You can use ````filter()```` with callback function ````return excluded.indexOf(e) === -1;````

Comment: Thank you for contributing. Sorry that I wasn't fully clear before the question edit.

Comment: Edited my answer anyway.