# Same variable for multiple sheets but only execute if export button on one sheet is pressed

Tags: variables, google-apps-script, google-sheets, error-handling, export

I am trying to code an data export. The export is executed when a button is pressed and the script linked to the button will be executed. The data is transfered to a masterdata sheet.
The script is valid for 4 different sheets and i am trying to code it, so that i do not have to rename all the vaiables for each sheet.

I found some solution that i tried, by creating a variable with the sheet names and then call this variable in the following code.

Problem 1: Error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'copyTo' of null" occurs.

Problem 2: How to ensure that only the data from the sheet where the export button is pressed will be exported?

I tried a lot and cannot find a solution.

```
var sheetListArray = ["B1-Prozessfragen", "B2-Prozessfragen"];
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    for( var k = 1 ; k <= sheetListArray.length ; k++)
    ExportData1g (sheetListArray[k]);
    PB1g (sheetListArray[k]);
  
function ExportData1g (sheetname) {

  var result = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Fertig-Hacken gesetzt?", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL); {
  if (result === SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
      const ssh=ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
      const cell = ssh.getRange("CheckButton1").getValue();
      if (cell == "1" || "0") { 
      (PB1g ()); 
      } 
      else {return;} }
      else {return;} 
        }
     

const ssh=ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
var dataRange = ssh.getRange('CheckBox1');
var values = dataRange.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
  if (values[i][j] == true) {
    values[i][j] = false; 
  }}
dataRange.setValues(values);


var commentRange = ssh.getRange ('ResetComment1');
var dataRange = ssh.getRange('EmptyBoxes1');
var values = dataRange.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
  if (values[i][j] == 1) {
    values[i][j] = 0; 
  }
}
}
commentRange.clearContent();
dataRange.setValues(values); 
  } }
  
function PB1g(sheetname)  { 

    const ssh=ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
    const tss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("1wMw5H48Fmc1R8WGy34d80x9-W996c9GNVuAD3-mFtVQ");
    const tsh=tss.getSheetByName("PB");
    const nsh=ssh.copyTo(tss);

    var firstEmtyRow = tsh.getLastRow () + 1;
    var timestamp = new Date();

    tsh.appendRow([timestamp]);

    nsh.getRange("CopytoMasterdata1").copyTo(tsh.getRange("B" + firstEmtyRow), {contentsOnly:true});
    tss.deleteSheet(nsh); }
```

Comment: Are you saying that when a button is pressed, your code is executed? Are you referring to the 'Run' button in the Apps Script IDE?

Comment: Can you link me the tutorial you followed? As right now your syntax is all out of whack, and that might be a factor in your current issue

Comment: @LoftonGentry Thank you very much for your reply. Regarding the button: Its not the run button in AppScript, its a drawing I added to the sheet and where I link the script.

Comment: @LoftonGentry Here is the tutorial i tried to follow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48206657/one-function-for-multiple-sheets-in-google-sheets

This refers to the first part of my code. The rest of the code (function ExportData1g and function PB1g) worked fine, as long as I referred at "get.SheetByName" to the real name of the sheet. But then the code only works for that particular sheet and i will have 4 sheets that should use the same function.

Comment: I would need the button's programming as well. Is that in HTML? Because adding a button that a user presses adds a whole other dimension of complication to the problem you're having